Problems compiling \xrightarrow with XeLaTeX?
When I compiled the code X_n\xrightarrow{p}X with the compiler XeLaTeX, I found that the length of the arrow and the vertical position of the "p" were very different from the result compiled with LaTeX. This is shown in the figure below:


I've tried adding the extarrows macro package and using \xlongrightarrow{p} to solve the arrow length problem, however, it doesn't solve the p position problem, what code should I use to make the effect in XeLaTeX as similar as possible to LaTeX?

I tried, but I see no perceivable difference between the output with pdflatex and XeLaTeX. With the former the output is similar to your second picture, but the “p” is lower, which makes me think you're loading unicode-math. Please, make examples that produce both pictures.

The different height is due to how the different bounding boxes for the arrow in legacy CM fonts and in Latin Modern Math.

@egreg Sorry, I realized that I did misremember, I also used \xlongrightarrow when compiling with LaTeX. thanks for pointing out the reason for the difference in heights, but what code should I use to fix this?

A bit of history: the original arrows Knuth designed had smaller heads

In 1992, he changed them to

(pictures from the manual of old-arrows). However, not wanting to change the metric files, the bounding box of the arrow remained the same as in the pre-1992 fonts.
The Latin Modern fonts used when unicode-math is used have a “full” bounding box for the arrows, so the superscript will be placed (a lot) higher.
Fix?
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\def\CM@rightarrow{\mathpalette\CM@@rightarrow\relax}
\def\CM@@rightarrow#1#2{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0.75\height]{$\m@th#1\rightarrow$}%
}
\def\rightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\CM@rightarrow}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\[
X_{n} \xrightarrow{p} X
\]

\end{document}


You need more for extarrows:
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{extarrows}
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\makeatletter
\def\CM@rightarrow{\mathpalette\CM@@rightarrow\relax}
\def\CM@@rightarrow#1#2{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0.75\height]{$\m@th#1\rightarrow$}%
}
\def\CM@longrightarrow{\mathpalette\CM@@longrightarrow\relax}
\def\CM@@longrightarrow#1#2{%
  \raisebox{0pt}[0.75\height]{$\m@th#1\longrightarrow$}%
}
\def\rightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\CM@rightarrow}
\def\xlongrightarrowfill@{\arrowfill@\relbar\relbar\CM@longrightarrow}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{gather*}
X_{n} \xrightarrow{p} X \\
X_{n} \xlongrightarrow{p} X
\end{gather*}

\end{document}


